# Close application after reading upper code c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am working with arduino serial monitor. My goal is to connect through serial port, send some data and close the application after it's done.

This is a C# application. Everything works well besides the fact that the application does not close. To solve the issue, I added `Application.Exit()` call at the end of `Form1_Load` method. After this change, the application starts and closes without reading the uppercase letter that I'm sending.

Source code:

```
namespace ForTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                try
                {
                    sp.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        sp.WriteLine("Z"); // Send 1 to Arduino
                        sp.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                 }
                catch (Exception ek)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ek.Message);
                }

            }

            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: So the program doesn't send the letter?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood properly, you want to send data **FROM C#** to **ARDUINO** and then you exit the C# app
you can't just call `Application.exit()` after the `InitializeComponent(),` instead to achieve that you need to exit after sending the data

```
sp.WriteLine("Z"); // Send 1 to Arduino
sp.Close();
Application.Exit();     ///here!!
```

Comment: Ok,sir I will try that.